# How to use `git_note` from libgit2?

Tags: libgit2

I've got code (where `commit_id` is already set) like:

```
  git_note* note;
  git_note_read(&note, repo, "refs/notes/label", &commit_oid);
  printf("%s\n", note->message);
  git_note_free(note);
```

It doesn't compile, complaining:

```
.../importer_test.cc:103:22: error: member access into incomplete type 'git_note'
  printf("%s\n", note->message);
                     ^
.../include/git2/types.h:160:16: note: forward declaration of 'git_note'
typedef struct git_note git_note;
```

If I just copy/paste from `src/notes.h` into this file:

```
struct git_note {
  git_oid id;
  git_signature *author;
  git_signature *committer;
  char *message;
};
```

It compiles and runs correctly.  But surely that's not the right solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git_note` is an opaque type. You're not meant to access members of the data directly. You should be using the accessor functions to read from it. In your case, you would want to use `git_note_message()` to get the message.

Comment: Thanks that's simple!  Can I ask how I'm supposed to know this?  E.g. https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/note/git_note_read takes a pointer to the read note, https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/commit/git_commit_lookup takes a pointer to the commit -- I can access properties of the commit but not the note.  The docs don't seem to communicate this?

Comment: The api docs just outlines all of the functions defined and doesn't go in depth to the level you're looking for. The examples (https://libgit2.org/docs/guides/101-samples/#commits_properties) however shows how to access properties for commits, I don't think you're supposed to access them directly either, the `git_commit` type is also opaque (https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/2a51679005285e4e5f8642dd86dc35b46de772c1/include/git2/types.h#L127).

Comment: I'd just look at the include file and see to what level the type is defined. If it shows the members, then you probably should be able to access them. If not, then there are probably functions to manipulate that type. All the types in the `git2.h` file seem to be opaque.